# cannot readd property push of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to put together my first app using react-native-navigation and I am taking pieces from the available examples on the web site.

Anyway, I am now trying to use a push function to have a new screen displayed, but the navigator seems to be undefined:

the structure is:

```
- app.js
  - firstScreenTab
      - pushScreenTab
  - secondScreenTab
```

The navigator is obviously defined in the app.js file.

In my firstScreenTab:

```
testNavPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        screen: 'manager.SecondTabScreen',
    title: 'Pushed Screen'
});
}

 <Button onPress={this.testNavPress.bind(this)}>
      Push
 </Button>
```

`

I set up my app using redux, I am wondering how should I pass my navigator as prop?

The start app function in my **app.js** looks like this:

```
startApp(root) {
console.log(root);
console.log('START APP!!!!!');

const tabs = [
  {
      label: 'Employees', // tab label as appears under the icon in iOS (optional)
      screen: 'manager.EmployeeListScreen', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
      icon: require('../img/one.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon unselected state (optional on iOS)
      selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon selected state (optional, iOS only. On Android, Use `tabBarSelectedButtonColor` instead)
      iconInsets: { // add this to change icon position (optional, iOS only).
        top: 6, // optional, default is 0.
        left: 0, // optional, default is 0.
        bottom: -6, // optional, default is 0.
        right: 0 // optional, default is 0.
      },
      title: 'Employee List', // title of the screen as appears in the nav bar (optional)
      navigatorStyle: {}, // override the navigator style for the tab screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional),
      navigatorButtons: {
        rightButtons: [

              {
                icon: require('../img/navicon_add.png'), // for icon button, provide the local image asset name
                id: 'add' // id for this button, given in onNavigatorEvent(event) to help understand which button was clicked
              }
            ]
      } // override the nav buttons for the tab screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
    },
  {
      label: 'One', // tab label as appears under the icon in iOS (optional)
      screen: 'manager.FirstTabScreen', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
      icon: require('../img/one.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon unselected state (optional on iOS)
      selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon selected state (optional, iOS only. On Android, Use `tabBarSelectedButtonColor` instead)
      iconInsets: { // add this to change icon position (optional, iOS only).
        top: 6, // optional, default is 0.
        left: 0, // optional, default is 0.
        bottom: -6, // optional, default is 0.
        right: 0 // optional, default is 0.
      },
      title: 'Screen One', // title of the screen as appears in the nav bar (optional)
      navigatorStyle: {}, // override the navigator style for the tab screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional),
      navigatorButtons: {} // override the nav buttons for the tab screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
    },
    {
      label: 'Two',
      screen: 'manager.SecondTabScreen',
      icon: require('../img/two.png'),
      selectedIcon: require('../img/two_selected.png'),
      title: 'Screen Two'
    }
];


switch (root) {
  case 'user':
     Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
      tabs,
      tabsStyle: {
        tabBarButtonColor: 'white',
        tabBarSelectedButtonColor: 'white',
        tabBarBackgroundColor: '#099880'
      }
    });
    break;
  default: 
     Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
      screen: {
        screen: 'manager.LoginScreen', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
        title: 'Log in', // title of the screen as appears in the nav bar (optional)
        navigatorStyle: {}, // override the navigator style for the screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional)
        navigatorButtons: {} // override the nav buttons for the screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
      }
    });
  }
  } // startApp
}
export default App;
```

I browsed other questions but most of them refer to react-navigation, I am using react-native-navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigation.startTabBasedApp` doesn't use a `navigator` - it simply invokes a native method that constructs the UI according to the object you've provided.

Make sure you call `super(props)` in `firstScreentab` so RNN can inject the navigator into your screen.

Comment: Thank you @guy.gc, I had to restructure a little my code because I am including a component which also needs the navigator passed at prop, but at the end it worked fine!